# Firefox and Safari show inline-block elements aligned differently inside other block

Tags: html, css, safari

I have inline block element (red circle) inside other block with some paddings. In Firefox this looks correctly and circle located at the middle of block occupied by equal paddings. However in Safari this looks incorrectly - circle a little bit moved to top and not centered vertically. I tried different **vertical-align** and **line-height** settings but this does not help, in Safari this still looks to different not like in Firefox.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="post-categories">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="cat-dot"></span>Uncategorized
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  line-height: 1.7;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.post-categories {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.post-categories a {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1px 15px 1px 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.post-categories .cat-dot {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    line-height: 14px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Codepen** where you can check this: https://codepen.io/dedalx/pen/xxbbMOo

Question - How I can make circle and text vertically centered in parent block in the same way in all modern browsers?

Comment: avoid odd values like 13px, centring hates them. Consider even ones

Comment: Of course, the easiest way that you can use now is using `flex`. Do your requirements allow this? What browsers do you have to support?

Comment: Try remove `top: 1px;` & `line-height: 14px;` from the `.post-categories .cat-dot` and add `.post-categories a > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}` Unfortunately I don't have Safari so can not check it there. But it should work fine, I guess.

Comment: @Konrud this giving issues even in Firefox - https://codepen.io/dedalx/pen/xxbbMOo (updated with your code). Circle is not aligned vertically in middle, it have more gap at top.

Comment: @Konrud I understand that flex will work here, but this will require add another tag (span/div) for text title near dot. I want to avoid this to have less tags in overall document, because this is category element and entries have a lot of them.

Comment: @Konrud and more important I want to understand why current code give issues and works differently in Firefox and Safari. I understand that browsers have different defaults for vertical-align, but even when this set as middle it not aligned by middle..

Comment: @Dmitry, first of all check the dimensions of the `post-categories` in the developer tools in FF and Chrome they are different. It can be because of how browsers render the "Arial" font-family. Try to check it, for me the text looks a bit different in each browser.